# Autoencoder maximal activation

Tags: data-visualization, autoencoders

I am trying to visualize what change each hidden unit of my autoencoder represents in my input space.

So I was wondering, why do people only look at the maximal activation of a hidden unit in an autoencoder (i.e. [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/Autoencoders/) under "Visualizing a Trained Autoencoder") and never at the minimal activation?

The weight matrix of a hidden unit can have positive and negative values which will obviously counteract each other when multiplied with a data example.

So should we not be looking at the change/difference between the inputs that cause maximal and minimal activation of a hidden unit to see what that hidden unit encodes?